# Are correlation coefficients related to the power on each variable

Tags: python, optimization, regression, curve-fitting

I have a few variables (x1, x2, x3, and x4), along with dependent variable Y. I am trying to use curve_fit for the regression analysis. Each variable has different correlation coefficient with Y. Assuming the function follows the form of Y = A * x1^a * x2^b * x3^c * x4^d, where A, a,b,c,d will be determined by curve_fit.

I was thinking the higher correlation coefficient variable has the higher power. For example, x1 has the highest correlation coefficient with Y, then 'a' has the largest value than 'b','c', and 'd'. However, the curve_fit does not give such assumption. And seems it is not quite relevant. Why is that?

I was thinking maybe the order of values matters. For example, x1 ranges around 1000, x2 ranges ~10, therefore, x1 weights more than x2, even though x2 has higher correlation coefficient than x1. I divide x1 by 100, make it have the same range with x2, but the power determined from curve_fit is the same!

It really confuses me. Thank you in advance for the clarification.

Comment: Suppose you have two variables, one which is generated like this: `X1 = Y^0.5 + random`, and one which is generated like `X2 = Y + random` The one which is the square root will have a lower correlation than the one which is linearly related, but the ideal power for the X1 is 2, and the ideal power for X2 is 1. Therefore this pattern doesn't hold in general.